# C# code to add cursors style as pointer

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a `HyperLink` in the code behind and adding it in a `Div`.
I want to add an attribute, so that cursor style must become `Hand`.

Comment: That's the default as long as the link actually goes somewhere.  Otherwise, you need to set it in css.

Comment: If you some style in css has removed the default style, you can assign a css class value to the hyperlink in the code behind and then define the style for the hyperlink in css file. e.g `.my-link {cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say your hyperlink control is `linkControl`. Then try this:

```
linkControl.Style["cursor"] = "pointer";
```

By the way, default `cursor` style for hyperlink is `pointer`

Answer (score 0):

Also You can set `Cursor` by code like below:

[image: Cursors]

Hope helps!